# Настроить вывод постов и в ленту новостей и в слайдер

Tags: php, wordpress

Первый опыт посадки верстки на wp у меня есть условная лента новостей, хочу реализовать чтобы из этой ленты четыре новости выводились и на слайдер (горячие новости), как такое реализовать? Ведь если создавать отдельную рубрику под это дело то это будет по сути две разные новости из слайдер и из ленты новостей... Надеюсь я понятно изложил мысль, помогите пожалуйста направьте на путь истинный))

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть лента новостей, и сделали вывод. То сделайте такой же вывод в слайдер, только выводите не все новости а первый 4. Счётчик, когда выведет первые 4 новости выйти из цикла. Как-то так)))